# Continuity of restriction map

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and suppose $X=\bigcup_i U_i$ is a union of open subsets. Prove that if all the restrictions $f_i=f|_{U_i}:U_i\rightarrow Y$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

Proof: For any $U$ open in $Y$, we have $f_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $U_i$ by assumption. Hence $f_i^{-1}(U)=U_i \cap V$ for some open set $V$ in X. Since $U_i$ is open in $X$, we have $f_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. But then we also have $f_i^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U) \cap U_i$, hence
$$f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)\cap X = f^{-1}(U) \cap \bigcup_i U_i= \bigcup_i f^{-1}(U)\cap U_i=\bigcup_i f_i^{-1}(U)$$ 
is a union of open sets, hence open.

My question is, why can't we just say $V=f^{-1}(U)$? If $A \cap B = C \cap B$, does it implies $A=C$? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not true that if $A\cap B=C\cap B$ then $A=C$. For example, let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $C=\{2,50,800\}$, and $B=\{2\}$. Then $A\cap B=\{2\}=C\cap B$, but clearly $A\not= C$. This is why you cannot conclude that $V=f^{-1}(U)$.